# API calls served over HTTP instead of HTTPs results in error in React/Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I'm using an API to fetch movie data using axios in my React app. While this works in localhost, I've recently uploaded this to github pages where it no longer works and it results in this error.

"Mixed content: load all resources via HTTPS to improve the security of your site"

My code is shown below:

```
const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchTitle}&type=movie&page=${searchPage}&y=${searchYear}&apikey=myapikeyhere`
      );
      if (result.data.totalResults) {
        console.log("fetching data:", result.data.Search);
        setQueryLength(result.data.Search.length);
        setMovieQuery(result.data.Search);
      } else {
        setMovieQuery([]);
        setQueryLength(0);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
```

This code is contained within a useEffect hook, when a user enters data into a text field movies are supposed to appear corresponding to the movie title. Nothing is being printed in my github pages site and I'm getting the error detailed above. I've never actually encountered this error before and I look forward to getting some feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `https` and not `http`

```
const result = await axios(
    `https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchTitle}&type=movie&page=${searchPage}&y=${searchYear}&apikey=myapikeyhere`
);
```

Comment: Thanks, was not aware that it was this easy haha

Answer (score 1):

You need to use https in your endpoint link

```
const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchTitle}&type=movie&page=${searchPage}&y=${searchYear}&apikey=myapikeyhere`
      );
      if (result.data.totalResults) {
        console.log("fetching data:", result.data.Search);
        setQueryLength(result.data.Search.length);
        setMovieQuery(result.data.Search);
      } else {
        setMovieQuery([]);
        setQueryLength(0);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Was not aware how easy of a solution this would be

Comment: you are welcom Please accept the answer if it works.